# Pairwise differences between two matrices in Eigen

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

In `matlab`/`octave` pairwise distances between matrices as required for e.g. k-means are calculated by one function call (see [cvKmeans.m](http://sourceforge.net/p/cvprtoolbox/code/HEAD/tree/cvKmeans.m)), to `distFunc(Codebook, X)` with as arguments two matrices of dimensions `K`x`D`.

In `Eigen` this can be done for a matrix and one vector by using broadcasting, as explained on [eigen.tuxfamily.org](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html):

```
 (m.colwise() - v).colwise().squaredNorm().minCoeff(&index);
```

However, in this case `v` is not just a vector, but a matrix. What's the equivalent oneliner in Eigen to calculate such pairwise (Euclidean) distances across all entries between two matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the appropriate solution is to abstract this functionality into a function.  That function may well be templated; and it may well use a loop - the loop will be really short, after all.  Many matrix operations are implemented using loops - that's not a problem.

For example, given your example of...

```
MatrixXd p0(2, 4);
p0 <<
    1, 23, 6, 9,
    3, 11, 7, 2;

MatrixXd p1(2, 2);
p1 <<
    2, 20,
    3, 10;
```

then we can construct a matrix ***D*** such that ***D***(i,j) = |**p**<sub>0</sub>(i) - **p**<sub>1</sub>(j)|<sup>2</sup>

```
MatrixXd D(p0.cols(), p0.rows());
for (int i = 0; i < p1.cols(); i++)
    D.col(i) = (p0.colwise() - p1.col(i)).colwise().squaredNorm().transpose();
```

I think this is fine - we can use some broadcasting to avoid 2 levels of nesting: we iterate over ***p***<sub>1</sub>'s points, but not over ***p***<sub>0</sub>'s points, nor over their dimensions.

However, you can make a oneliner if you observe that *|**p**<sub>0</sub>(i) - **p**<sub>1</sub>(j)|<sup>2</sup> = |**p**<sub>0</sub>(i)|<sup>2</sup> + |**p**<sub>1</sub>(j)|<sup>2</sup> - 2 **p**<sub>0</sub>(i)<sup>T</sup> **p**<sub>1</sub>(j)*.  In particular, the last component is just matrix multiplication, so ***D*** = -2 **p**<sub>0</sub><sup>T</sup> **p**<sub>1</sub> + ...

The blank left to be filled is composed of a component that only depends on the row; and a component that only depends on the column: these can be expressed using rowwise and columnwise operations.

The final "oneliner" is then:

```
D = ( (p0.transpose() * p1 * -2
      ).colwise() + p0.colwise().squaredNorm().transpose()
    ).rowwise() + p1.colwise().squaredNorm();
```

You could also replace the rowwise/colwise trickery with an (outer) product with a **1** vector.

Both methods result in the following (squared) distances:

```
  1 410
505  10
 32 205
 50 185
```

You'd have to benchmark which is fastest, but I wouldn't be surprised to see the loop win, and I expect that's more readable too.

Answer (score 0):

Eigen is more of a headache than I thought on first sight.

1. There is no `reshape()` functionality for example (and `conservativeResize` is something else).
2. It also seems (I'd like to be corrected) to be the case that `Map` does not just offer a view on the data, but assignments to temporary variables seem to be required.
3. The `minCoeff` function after the `colwise` operator cannot return a minimum element and an index to that element.
4. It is unclear to me if `replicate` is actually allocating duplicates of the data. The reason behind broadcasting is that this is not required.

   ```
   matrix_t data(2,4);
   matrix_t means(2,2);

   // data points
   data << 1, 23, 6, 9,
           3, 11, 7, 2;

   // means
   means << 2, 20,
            3, 10;

   std::cout << "Data: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << data.replicate(2,1) << std::endl;

   column_vector_t temp1(4);
   temp1 = Eigen::Map<column_vector_t>(means.data(),4);

   std::cout << "Means: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << temp1.replicate(1,4) << std::endl;

   matrix_t temp2(4,4);
   temp2 = (data.replicate(2,1) - temp1.replicate(1,4));
   std::cout << "Differences: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << temp2 << std::endl; 

   matrix_t temp3(2,8);
   temp3 = Eigen::Map<matrix_t>(temp2.data(),2,8);
   std::cout << "Remap to 2xF: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << temp3 << std::endl;

   matrix_t temp4(1,8);
   temp4 = temp3.colwise().squaredNorm();
   std::cout << "Squared norm: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << temp4 << std::endl;//.minCoeff(&index);

   matrix_t temp5(2,4);
   temp5 = Eigen::Map<matrix_t>(temp4.data(),2,4);
   std::cout << "Squared norm result, the distances: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << temp5.transpose() << std::endl;

   //matrix_t::Index x, y;
   std::cout << "Cannot get the indices: " << std::endl;
   std::cout << temp5.transpose().colwise().minCoeff() << std::endl; // .minCoeff(&x,&y);
   ```

This is not a nice oneliner and seems overkill just to compare every column in `data` with every column in `means` and return a matrix with their differences. However, the versatility of Eigen does not seem to be such that this can be written down much shorter.